# Connection to DSL failed after configuring Bridge in centOS

Tags: linux, networking, bridge

I run CentOS 6.4. After configuring bridge I am unable to connect to internet through PPPoE Bsnl Dsl. I set up the bridge as follows:

```
DEVICE="br0"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Bridge
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no 
NAME="br0"
```

I added `BRIDGE= br0` at the end of eth0 file and set `Nm_controlled= no`. After `service network restart` I am unable to connect to DSL service.

Comment: A PPPoE connection provides but a single endpoint. Why would you want it to be part of a bridge? (Or is some other device the PPPoE endpoint?)

Answer (score 0):

Any special reason of configuring bridge because PPPoE over DSL broadband wouldn't work on bridging.

If you want you can use virtualization software like VMware for the bridging stuff to run internet on multiple machines.

Answer (score 0):

Since `bootproto = dhcp` I found out that for running DSL over bridge one needs to check whether the modem is able to work in bridge mode or not.

I checked my modem configuration and found that it didn't support bridge. I changed my modem and I was able to run DSL over bridge. I was actually connecting two VMs and my root OS to bridge and connecting DSL to bridge.